# How can I solve "ValueError - Cannot serialize"?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have an error in my Django project. When I run the 'python manage.py makemigrations' command then comes the error.

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001B5A3078940>

#### File *models.py*

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quntity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=Product.price)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    print(Product.price)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.product.name
```

#### File *admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Order

# Register your models here.


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    models = Order
    list_display =['product', 'customer', 'quntity', 'price', 'address', 'phone', 'date']

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

#### Error page

[image]

Comment: *"quntity"* is a misspelling of *"[quantity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantity#Noun)"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a default value to filed with `default=Product.price`

So change this line

```
price = models.IntegerField(default=Product.price)
```

to

```
price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and if you want to set the order price from the product price, you can override the save() method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.product is not None:
        self.price = self.product.price

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: after override save method it's work, but why this error come?

Comment: you getting the same ValueError?

Comment: but whit out save method it's also save but why nedd to do this

Comment: unless you enter the price in order manually, without this save method order.price will 0, got it..?

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem in the *price* attribute. You can use *def save()*, not default.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).